# Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE' while creating trigger in azure data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a trigger in sql data warehouse. It gives me

> Incorrect syntax near 'CREATE'

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_save_impactcount]
ON [dbo].[SoverityProjectsDefects]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DBO.SoverityProjectsDefectsImpact 
           ([displayImpactCategory]
           ,[ImpactCount]
           ,[current_timestamp]
           ,[FileNameUUID])
    SELECT displayImpact, count(displayImpact) as impactCount, [current_timestamp],[FileNameUUID] FROM INSERTED 
GROUP BY displayImpact, [current_timestamp], [FileNameUUID];
END
```

anyone knows a fix for this in azure data warehouse?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER isn't valid syntax there https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse - the menu on the left gives you valid options for CREATE. TRIGGER isn't one of them

Comment: Nice spot, @MartinSmith . For confirmation, see [Design tables using dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics - Unsupported table features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview#unsupported-table-features), which explicitly lists triggers.

Comment: Thank you. I need to figure out other way to execute this now. :)

Comment: Why do you need to "pre-compute" a count? Is this premature optimization? It is a bit odd to change names of what seems like an important column during your insert (displayImpact becomes displayImpactCategory).